# PlayOnLinux / WINE error. Cannot add games to list

Tags: playonlinux, steam

I am new to the Linux platform as a whole. Now, that's not to say that I haven't been watching countless videos and articles of Linux before I made the switch.

I have gone through multiple tutorials but I just can't seem to install games that are not listed within PlayOnLinux. It just simply doesn't show the game in the list. I have Killing Floor installed on Steam (which is on POL) but cannot seem to add Killing Floor to the list in PlayOnLinux. I can launch Killing Floor from Steam but there is no audio and it is slightly laggy.

Any help - relative to the above issue or not - is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I really need help. Bump!